# Getting to the bottom of excessive logs?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, logging

I'm a fairly new Android phone user and I have a question about excessive logs.

My phone battery is pretty awful (Elephone P9000) so I thought I'd hook it up and look at LogCat. In just over 20 seconds it logs nearly 5000 lines when idle with the screen off. That sounds like a bit much to me? Most of the log is filled with the same pattern repeating:

```
    05-31 13:26:40.559: I/fanzhuan(980): onSensorChanged front----> 0.361  0.497  10.07
05-31 13:26:40.571: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18369600), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.591: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18369920), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.612: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18370240), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.631: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18370560), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.651: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18370880), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.671: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18371200), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.691: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18371520), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.711: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18371840), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.731: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18372160), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.751: D/AudioTrackShared(293): front(18372480), mIsOut(0), mAvailToClient=0 stepCount=320 minimum=320, FUTEX_WAKE
05-31 13:26:40.758: D/SettingsInterface(980):  from settings cache , name = turn_silent , value = null
05-31 13:26:40.758: D/SettingsInterface(980):  from settings cache , name = callsilent , value = null
05-31 13:26:40.759: D/SettingsInterface(980):  from settings cache , name = alarmsilent , value = null
05-31 13:26:40.759: D/SettingsInterface(980):  from settings cache , name = musicsilent , value = null
05-31 13:26:40.759: D/SettingsInterface(980):  from settings cache , name = mediasilent , value = null
```

Is this normal? I've had a google and I can't see may people talking about this. Also, how do I go about finding what's causing this so I can kill it?

Maybe it's totally unrelated to my battery drain, but this amount of constant logging sounds little excessive to me.

Thanks for your time and help :-)

P.S. Running Android 6.0

Comment: This is a common symptom of phones having poor-quality system integration, but the amount you have seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

The `D/` entries show the log level is set to "DEBUG" – which of course generates quite a lot of logging, and shouldn't be necessary for "production use" (though it's quite helpful if you want to debug some misbehavior). For normal use, log level "INFO" should be sufficient.

As the default log level usually is defined in the init script, there's not much a "standard user" (without root-powers) can do about it, though. You can filter the output, though, as [described on the logcat help page](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html#outputFormat): so `adb logcat *:I` should only show messages using log level INFO or above. You could try `run adb shell setprop log.tag.* INFO`, but I'm not sure if that works; and even if it does, it would be reset at boot.

Apart from that, I can't say whether that would improve your battery life noticeably. For that purpose, you probably find better hints in our [battery-life tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info).